# Return loop value in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, return

How to display loop value in another class?

**Class B**

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WelcomePage welcome = new WelcomePage();
        String a = welcome.run();
        System.out.println("The output " + a);
    }
}
```

**Class WelcomePage**

```
public String run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           return "Hello";
        }
         return "Hello";
    }
```

The program only display Hello. How can I display multiple Hello ?

Comment: You can't return more than once from a method. If you want it to print multiple times, you'll have to do it from inside the loop.

Comment: Use `System.out.println` in the loop; Use `StringBuilder` to concatenate the values from the loop into a single `String`

Comment: You'll need to collect the results of your loop iterations into a Collection like ArrayList or Set and return that. Then you can work on those in your calling code. I don't suppose you just want to display that. If you only want to display multiple Hello, use a StringBuilder and collect all your Strings in it, maybe separated by a space, and return that to be displayed in your calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a string and append all Values, after you can return your string like this :

```
public String run() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           sb.append("Hello");
        }
         return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: wrong code there no need in str. just return sb.toString()

Comment: thx, forgot to declare String str, however you right , it's not usefull

Answer (score 1):

Class B only displays one Hello from WelcomePage because the run() method is only called once, and when a return is hit, be it in a loop or not, returns the value and then moves to the next line of code after the method call.

As the other answers suggest, you can make a String and append Hello\n which will display;

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

or else remove the \n to have Hello printed in one line.

I would suggest removing the for loop from the run() method and put it in the main method of Class B, then within the for loop have your call to the run method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    String a = welcome.run();
    System.out.println("The output " + a);
}
```

Have the run() method just return Hello

```
public String run(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   return "Hello";
}
 return "Hello";
```

The function return once in each execution.So, the best way is to put the loop in the mail method. Something like this.

```
public class Runner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WelcomePage welcome = new WelcomePage();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    String a = welcome.run();
    System.out.println("The output " + a);
   }}}
```

and just return the hello from run method.

```
public String run() {
     return "Hello";
}
```